# Ubuntu - Media Centre Desktop - No Digital Surround - No Blu-ray

Tags: 11.10, home-theatre

I purchased new Asus m5a88-m motherboard - 8G RAM,  64 bit, 64 G SSD to build xbmc over full desktop Ubuntu 64 bit - tried 3 versions of Ubuntu between 10 and 11.

System is lightning fast, good in all respects except I cannot get the s/PDIF to output digital surround to my receiver, and, it does not seem to recognize and be able to play blu-ray movies.

I am coming from the windows world - where I have built a few MCPC's - and thought how nice it would be to do this with Ubuntu - I hope this is reasonable, and wanted to get help to make this happen - any ideas?

Comment: s/PDIF I can't help you with, but I can tell you that blu-ray is still a work in progress since whoever developed the copyright protection for it is a jerk.

Comment: Have you tried changing the settings ins Alsa-mixer (Sound Menu -> Sound Preferences) to see if you can get sPDIF output?

Comment: can you select the s/pdif output in the volume control (pavucontrol)?

Comment: Blu-Ray: I believe ths will be ok once I do my xbmc install - so I will leave that for now. The sPDIF will output digital stereo to my amp - but the options for analog surround when selected provide no output. (my amp can be configured to process digital or analog signals via the sPDIF input. I have found alot of references to solutions, so I am working through those. I have to laugh though - next time someone bashes MS - I will remind myself  about their strong points...

Comment: I found a post that suggest to uninstall pulse audio - I did this, and now analog sound will output through the spdif. I beleive the next step is to customize the driver output by adding digital surround in the config. Will post follow up with links if this works.